# how to plot histogram chart using flot plugin in javascript?

Tags: javascript, flot

I want to plot histogram type chart using flot plugin. I know how to plot barchart in flot. Is it similar to barchart?

Comment: No built-in function, you have to code it yourself.

Comment: can you help how to code?

Comment: No. Stackoverflow is not a code-generating service. Try to do it yourself based on your bar chart. And if you have specific problems or questions you can come back and show your existing code.